# What do you call cent, øre, etc (money less than 1 unit) in general?

Tags: word-meaning

I am writing something and I need to talk about cents,øre, etc in general. What do you call that?

The only word that I can think of, is change but one can use it also for $5 out of $100.

Comment: Are you referring to **coins**?  Coins can be less than or greater than the standard unit, although the latter are rare nowadays. Or  are you referring to fractional values that result from division (e.g. rounding errors in an accounting system)?

Comment: The most generic term seems to be **subunit**.

Comment: And what is the context for this word?  Are you at a convenience store complaining to the person at the cash register that you were shortchanged? Or are you describing software that can be used by a multinational corporation to track its investments?  "writing something" is not much help.

Comment: @TRomano I didn't mean coins. We have 2 euro coin but I didn't mean that. I think something like centesimal can do the job. But I will wait to see if someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may call it the **[centesimal unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(currency)) of a particular currency**.

Quoting from the link:

> "Examples of currencies around the world featuring **centesimal ( 1⁄100) units** called **cent**, or related words from the same root such as céntimo, centésimo, centavo or sen, are..."

Also:

[image]

and:

[image]

Comment: *Centesimal* is definitely a good word to know, although it's pretty uncommon (I didn't know it off the top of my head) and it only applies to 1/100th divisions.  Admittedly, that is most of the currencies in the world, but [there are some exceptions...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-decimal_currency)